# Aggregation operation to modify the key of a property from a subdocument of documents

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have in mongo db a collection with documents like this:

```
{
    "prop1": "val1",
    "prop2": {
        "prop21": {
            "toBeChanged1_xyz": "val2",
            "toBeChanged2_zyx": "val3",
        },
        "prop22": {
            "whatever": "something"
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to create aggregation operation in Java Spring to remove from the keys of `prop21`'s properties the substring after `_`. This if what I need to have:

```
{
    "prop1": "val1",
    "prop2": {
        "prop21": {
            "toBeChanged1": "val2",
            "toBeChanged2": "val3",
        },
        "prop22": {
            "whatever": "something"
        }
    }
}
```

Tried something like this:

```
List<AggregationOperation> operations = new ArrayList<AggregationOperation>();
        operations.add( Aggregation.project( "code" ).and( "code" ).minus( "_"+"$entityType" ).as( "newId" ));
```

It didn't worked, of course. I have no idea how can it be done or can it be done easier in other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your structure to below.

```
{
  "prop1": "val1",
  "prop2": [
    {
      "prop": "prop21",
      "value": [
        {
          "prop": "toBeChanged1_xyz",
          "value": "val2"
        },
        {
          "prop": "toBeChanged2_zyx",
          "value": "val3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "prop": "prop22",
      "value": [
        {
          "prop": "whatever",
          "value": "something"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can try below query in 3.4. The query will iterate over property elements and locate `prop2` and `$split` to modify the property name.

```
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "prop2": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$prop2",
          "as": "prop_2",
          "in": {
            "prop": "$$prop_2.prop",
            "value": {
              "$cond": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$$prop_2.prop",
                    "prop21"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$map": {
                    "input": "$$prop_2.value",
                    "as": "prop_21",
                    "in": {
                      "prop": {
                        "$arrayElemAt": [
                          {
                            "$split": [
                              "$$prop_21.prop",
                              "_"
                            ]
                          },
                          0
                        ]
                      },
                      "value": "$$prop_21.value"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "$$prop_2.value"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

You can use the below query if you cant modify the structure from 3.4.4 version.

The query uses `$arrayToObject` and `$objectToArray` operator to modify the documents to above structure with same logic to modify the property name.

```
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "prop2": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$objectToArray": "$prop2"
            },
            "as": "prop_2",
            "in": {
              "k": "$$prop_2.k",
              "v": {
                "$cond": [
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$prop_2.k",
                      "prop21"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$arrayToObject": {
                      "$map": {
                        "input": {
                          "$objectToArray": "$$prop_2.v"
                        },
                        "as": "prop_21",
                        "in": {
                          "k": {
                            "$arrayElemAt": [
                              {
                                "$split": [
                                  "$$prop_21.k",
                                  "_"
                                ]
                              },
                              0
                            ]
                          },
                          "v": "$$prop_21.v"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "$$prop_2.v"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```